# Not working JavaScript AutoComplete in eclipse Photon

Tags: eclipse, javascript, autocomplete

I download "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" (Photon), create project as "Dynamic Web Project", then add html file and in  tag JavaScript AutoComplete not working. When adding javascript file - the same. What what need to do to enable JavaScript AutoComplete?